# Does PSS (Proportional Set Size) number for a process include the memory consumed by kernel code?

Tags: linux, memory, process, uss

I used the smem command to find PSS/USS numbers for a process.

As per the smem man page, "The unshared memory (USS) plus a process's proportion of shared memory is reported as the PSS (Proportional Set Size)."

Now does all the Linux kernel code resident in memory get included when PSS is calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO it does not contain the kernel portion of memory.